# IllegalArgumentException from closing service that draws on other apps

Tags: android, android-service, android-view

I am writing an android app that runs a service in the background that makes use of the `OVERLAY_PERMISSION` to draw on other apps. It starts with an intent from a button on my main activity. So far, so good.

In my service, in my `onDestroy()`, I have a `if (myView != null) windowManager.removeView(myView);`. And when I call stopService from the activity, I get an error, saying:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.supernovaapps.cameralevel.LevelService@ed1633f: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.AbsoluteLayout{94fb155 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
```

I am only able to close the service if I comment out that line. However, if I do that, the view remains on the screen even after the service is closed, which is not what I want.

What is the correct way to close the service and detach the view?

Full Trace:

```
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.supernovaapps.cameralevel, PID: 21233
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.supernovaapps.cameralevel.LevelService@ed1633f: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.AbsoluteLayout{94fb155 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3059)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1447)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.AbsoluteLayout{94fb155 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:424)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:350)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:111)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.supernovaapps.cameralevel.LevelService.onDestroy(LevelService.java:164)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3040)
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1447) 
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-20 20:16:10.042 21233-21233/com.supernovaapps.cameralevel E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: looks like you passed a different view to windowManager than what was added to it before.

Comment: More stacktrace information would be handy ..

Comment: @Radix sorry, adding full stacktrace. Also, its the same view, but I removed and added it a bunch of times in the middle. That shouldn't cause any issues, right?

Comment: It doesn't sound right to be operating directly on views from services - the lifecycle isn't really designed to cope with it. Maybe a pub-sub/event bus/callback to the view controller..?

Comment: @Radix nvm, you were right about it being a different view. Thanks so much. Put it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: you could also look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23586127/2745762

Comment: @saywhatnow I'm using sensor data to update the view from the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you passed a different view to windowManager than what was added to it before. 
Just pass it the right view and it would work.