# IllegalArgumentException for ProgressDialog.dismiss() when it is showing

Tags: android, progressdialog

Here is the simple code:

```
if (myProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on why myProgressDialog.dismiss() sometimes causes the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{83559f5 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,348} not attached to window manager
Stack trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{83559f5 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,348} not attached to window manager
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:424)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:350)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:362)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:345)
```

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: "View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{83559f5 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,348} not attached to window manager".
Error saying your dialog no longer attached to your current fragment/activity. check your fragment/activity is still visible before your dialog is close.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  It is occasionally reported in the log from users.  I cannot reproduce this.  I have just added code to check the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your activity is destroyed.
check if you have called finish() in your class before calling progress dialog..
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this fixed code:

```
 if (YourActivity.this.isDestroyed()) { // or call isFinishing() if min sdk version < 17
    return;
 } 
 if (myProgressDialog != null && myProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
    myProgressDialog.dismiss();
 }
```

ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23586127/6759520