# View not attached to window manager crash in xamarin forms android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Some of the users getting following crash randomly which is difficult to reproduce and debug.

This is Xamarin forms project and I wrote interface to android project from portable project to call and dismiss dialog.

Below is the stack trace:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: View=DecorView@436ca9e[MainActivity] not attached 
to window manager
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] 
in <793d884878e04897966a5f2be50d2777>:0 
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod 
(Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, 
Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in 
<acbdf8c357bc4305803000756be43728>:0 
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod 
(System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, 
Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in 
<acbdf8c357bc4305803000756be43728>:0 
at Android.App.Dialog.Cancel () [0x0000a] in 

--- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=DecorView@436ca9e[MainActivity] not 
attached to window manager
at 
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:479)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:388)
at 
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:128)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:610)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:593)
at android.app.Dialog.cancel(Dialog.java:1508)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

How to identify this crash?

Comment: Did you watch this [View not attached to window manager crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924825/view-not-attached-to-window-manager-crash)

Comment: Yes. But in my xamarin forms project I am not finishing the activities/pages. I am trying to open a new page on top of it.

Comment: Like a popup or full screen modal ?

Comment: yes like a popup

Comment: have you trying to use [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) ?

Comment: Yes @FabriBertani. I am using the above plugin