# android: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android....... not attached to window manager

Tags: android

I have a problem with the progress dialog.

[The attach image is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l62v.png)

```
private void uploadFile() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Files, Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    if (audioFileUri != null){
        StorageReference imageReference = storageRef.child("updates_photo").child(engText.getText().toString().trim() + "");
        StorageReference audioRef = storageRef.child("updates_audio").child(engText.getText().toString().trim() + ""); // storage location to firebase.
        StorageReference fxRef = storageRef.child("updates_effect").child(engText.getText().toString().trim() + ""); // storage location to firebase

        // Upload attach audio file
        audioRef.putFile(audioFileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // Upload for attach effects audio file
        if(audioFxUri != null){
            fxRef.putFile(audioFxUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Effect Uploaded! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { // When loading progress is paused
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                    System.out.println("Upload is paused");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { // If progress fails
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Effect Failed! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { // During upload progress
                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/ taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + " % done");
                }
            });
        }

        // Upload for Image
        if(imageFileUri != null){
            imageReference.putFile(imageFileUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    //and displaying error message
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

The error shows in the onSuccess method in my `progressDialog.dismiss()`. How can I investigate this?

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23586127/4748607)

Comment: define progress dialog globally...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to a IF statement
`if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) { 
   progressDialog.dismiss();}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same problem as here -> [View not attached to window manager crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924825/view-not-attached-to-window-manager-crash) not entirely sure, but do take a gander at it.

Answer (score 0):

karen When are you calling the function "uploadFile()" if it is an on click, I think you should call the dialog.show() before the async process starts.

the code may be like this

```
 final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
 progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Files, Please wait...");

 buttonSubmit.OnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            progressDialog.show();
            uploadFile();
        }
    });

private void uploadFile() {
if (audioFileUri != null){
    StorageReference imageReference = storageRef.child("updates_photo").child(engText.getText().toString().trim() + "");
    StorageReference audioRef = storageRef.child("updates_audio").child(engText.getText().toString().trim() + ""); // storage location to firebase.
    StorageReference fxRef = storageRef.child("updates_effect").child(engText.getText().toString().trim() + ""); // storage location to firebase

    // Upload attach audio file
    audioRef.putFile(audioFileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    // Upload for attach effects audio file
    if(audioFxUri != null){
        fxRef.putFile(audioFxUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Effect Uploaded! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { // When loading progress is paused
                progressDialog.cancel();
                System.out.println("Upload is paused");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { // If progress fails
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Effect Failed! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { // During upload progress
                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/ taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + " % done");
            }
        });
    }

    // Upload for Image
    if(imageFileUri != null){
        imageReference.putFile(imageFileUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //and displaying error message
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```